# Responsive Images with Lazysizes plugin are not displaying in IE and Safari browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, lazy-loading

I'm using [Lazysizes](https://afarkas.github.io/lazysizes/) jquery plugin in one of my project, to load/display corresponding images according to the size of the browser window in a responsive view, The following is the code which display image on Chrome and Firefox browsers, but not in Safari and IE, it displays only white space instead of images.

```
<cfoutput>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lazysizes/2.0.7/lazysizes.min.js" async=""></script>

    <img 
    data-sizes="auto" 
    data-srcset="image01-sm.jpg 242w,
    image02-med.jpg 355w, 
    image03.jpg 392w" 
    class="lazyload" />

</cfoutput>
```

And if I used `data-src="image.jpg"` attribute on img tag means, that image alone displaying, and the images in `data-srcset` attribute are not loading. which is not responsive too. But everything works fine on chrome and FF browsers.

Not sure, why it is not working on those browsers(Safari and IE)? Did I missed anything ?

Comment: Why is this tagged as ColdFusion?

Comment: @ScottStroz Not necessary, but I've used the above code with CF, so tagged.